# Python Tornado web service for long running process

Tags: python, web-services, tornado

I want to write a web service which processes the request on the background. The service puts the request into a queue and responds the client immediately.

My problem in the code below is that while loop in BackgroundThread().run() function doesn't work.

While loop in BackgroundThread.run() method doesn't act like infinite.It only go into while loop once.

Thank you.

Code:

```
class BackgroundThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            item = queue.get()
            if item is not None:
                #long running process
                time.sleep(random.randint(10, 100) / 1000.0)
                print "task", item, "finished"

queue = Queue.Queue()

class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        global queue
        self.write('OK')
        self.finish()
        filePath = self.get_arguments("filePath")
        queue.put(filePath)
        print queue.qsize()

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        BackgroundThread().start()
        BackgroundThread().start()
        app = tornado.web.Application([(r'/', MyHandler)])
        print("server opened on port : 8000")
        server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
        server.bind(8000)
        server.start(4) # Specify number of subprocesses
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Worker.run() function doesn't work"?

Comment: I edited Worker to BackgroundThread. And  infinite loop in run function doesn't act like infinite. It only go into while loop once.

Answer (score 0):

I just add try except block because when queue is empty in while loop,it get an exception and doesn't iterate.

I got the answer and here is the code :

```
class BackgroundThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    global queue
    print("qwerqwer0")
    while 1==1:
        print("qwerqwer1")
        print("qwerqwer2")
        try:
            item = queue.get()
            queue.task_done()
        except Queue.Empty:
            print("empty")
            pass
        if item is not None:
            print("qwerqwerqwer")
            #long running process
            print "task ", item, " finished"

queue = Queue.Queue()

class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        global queue
        self.write('OK')
        self.finish()
        filePath = self.get_arguments("filePath")
        queue.put(filePath)
        print queue.qsize()

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        #BackgroundThread().start()
        BackgroundThread().start()
        app = tornado.web.Application([(r'/', MyHandler)])
        print("server opened on port : 8000")
        server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
        server.bind(8000)
        server.start(4) # Specify number of subprocesses
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
        sys.exit(1)
```